# Body Parameters Accepted in Query (ASP.Net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, appscan

Recently my project gone through yearly scan and some Vulnerabilities were found one of these is Body Parameters Accepted in Query I have searched a lot but could not found any solution for this. Can any one please help me with it.

**PDF content**

**CVSS Score:** 5.0

**Entity:** ViewGeneratedLicense.aspx (Page)

**Risk:** It is possible to gather sensitive information about the web application such as usernames,
passwords, machine name and/or sensitive file locations
It is possible to persuade a naive user to supply sensitive information such as username, password,
credit card number, social security number etc.
Causes: Insecure web application programming or configuration

**Fix:** Do not accept body parameters that are sent in the query string

Difference: Body Parameter removed from request:
dlEQnbwh+SU0fnNggvrn41XqVCYrGzcGkfx1U2vWIFuouDJj179CSwOlev0Kt8bKAywMLBjGIVsO3vKyfMN/Af4t
kLgsMCBjYKg3WCbLwP4OyLzHuNzwbmjFixYeKmsOgNg3Fm78wUEiU/A1Ylq6vy5kybGhTbFDjiUT7aK7RE48c3ry
PH9wOA/8dBSa4/gObQISeh9s1NCSvrKAXpWrGUJTZGSRQ6LacRwWjT/B1x4=

Query Parameter added to request:
dlEQnbwh+SU0fnNggvrn41XqVCYrGzcGkfx1U2vWIFuouDJj179CSwOlev0Kt8bKAywMLBjGIVsO3vKyfMN/Af4t
kLgsMCBjYKg3WCbLwP4OyLzHuNzwbmjFixYeKmsOgNg3Fm78wUEiU/A1Ylq6vy5kybGhTbFDjiUT7aK7RE48c3ry
PH9wOA/8dBSa4/gObQISeh9s1NCSvrKAXpWrGUJTZGSRQ6LacRwWjT/B1x4=

Body Parameter removed from request: 60E89E49 Query Parameter added to request: 60E89E49

Body Parameter removed from request:

Query Parameter added to request:

Body Parameter removed from request:
RTzm2ACJxwCcqznNO4Wvc54r2vCBI7D4zpx5pjId8Fa4ECNizBeorXO9wOTWYPXO9p6GxfhMRCINxxbw2xvSWf9P
9KPShEp7iXodQHNW/n9xdPVf9hRUq0fx4ZcUTASpv/Vau6AmreXgo6L8ceeLRO4mpW29Zvm/y6iH4dsj4jVZdX4i
b+Z/tnbdxZmSDVZC

Query Parameter added to request:
RTzm2ACJxwCcqznNO4Wvc54r2vCBI7D4zpx5pjId8Fa4ECNizBeorXO9wOTWYPXO9p6GxfhMRCINxxbw2xvSWf9P
9KPShEp7iXodQHNW/n9xdPVf9hRUq0fx4ZcUTASpv/Vau6AmreXgo6L8ceeLRO4mpW29Zvm/y6iH4dsj4jVZdX4i
b+Z/tnbdxZmSDVZC

Body Parameter removed from request: 1234 Query Parameter added to request: 1234
Body Parameter removed from request: Go Query Parameter added to request: Go Method manipulated from: POST to: GET Reasoning: The test result seems to indicate a vulnerability because the Test Response is similar to
the Original Response, indicating that the application processed body parameters that were
submitted in the query

I am not sure about solution? According to PDF Solution is given( Fix: Do not accept body parameters that are sent in the query string ????)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of ASP.NET you're using, but in older versions if you didn't explicitly tag a parameter with something like `[FromQuery]` or `[FromBody]`, ASP.NET would go through all of the possible sources and try to find the information. That would mean you could have code like this:

```cs
public class Credentials
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult DoSomething(Credentials credentials)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The *intent* is for a user to include the credentials (which is sensitive information)  in the request body. However, if you don't provide a body and *do* provide values in the query parameters, Asp.Net will find those values and bind them. The following request would work:

POST /api/Foo?Username=john&Password=pas$w0rd

That's a security risk, because query parameters are often logged in intermediate servers so the password could become visible in plain-text.

The solution is to evaluate these methods, and annotate the parameters appropriately so they are bound to query parameters *or* the request body *but not both*:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult DoSomething([FromBody] Credentials credentials)
```

Comment: I'm not using MVC bro.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. I didn't notice the source file was an ASPX file. Hopefully this answer at least helps you understand the issue that was described, and how the suggested fix resolves that - _Fix: Do not accept body parameters that are sent in the query string_.